# Archive files and dirs, some recursively, some non-recursively, using 7-Zip command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, archive, directory-structure, 7zip

I want to archive a bunch of files and dirs with a 7-Zip command line, to be executed as a shell script (bash shell on a Ubuntu 19.04 server).

In my main dir, there are two subdirs: `foo` and `bar`.

Both the `foo` and `bar` dirs contain subdirs, e.g. the directory structure is like this:

```
foo
 foo/abc
 foo/pqrs
 foo/etc...
bar
 bar/xyz
 bar/temp
 bar/etc...
```

I want to create one single 7z archive with:

- all contents of `foo` including its subdirs
- all files in `bar` but NOT in its subdirs

I can do this separately, but is there a way to do this in one go, perhaps using a @filelist.txt construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> perhaps using a @filelist.txt construction?

Using a wildcard seemed easier to me. E.g:

```
7z a -x'!bar/*/' my_archive.7z foo bar
```

---

The first solution I proposed was:

```
find foo bar \
     ! \( -type d -path 'bar/*' -prune \) \
     -type f \
     -exec 7z a 'my_archive.7z' {} +
```

This will do almost the same except there won't be directory entries in the archive index.